# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \left(\frac{n-1} {2n+2}\right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What is the easiest way to evaluate this limit?
$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(n-1 \over 2n+2\right)^n}$
$$
\text{Is this possible ?$\,$:}\quad
\lim_{n \to\infty}\left(n/n - 1/n \over 2n/n + 2/n\right)^n
=
\lim_{n \to\infty}\left(1 - 1/n \over 2 + 2/n\right)^{n}
=
\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(1 \over 2\right)^{n} = 0
$$

Comment: What if it was $\left(\frac{n-1}{n+2}\right)^n$?

Comment: The last line is wrong: you have $\lim \ (1-{1 \over n})^n=\exp(-1)$. Also, in all your limits, the variable is $n$, not $x$. Apart from that, your result is trivially true, since ${{n-1} \over {2n+2}}<1/2$.

Comment: @LukaToni You have the limit of $x \to \infty$, but the expression is in terms of $n$ so the answer would simply be $({\frac{n - 1}{2n + 2}})^n$.

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word.  "Evaluate" would be appropriate.  One solves problems; one solves equations; one _evaluates_ expressions.

Comment: The easiest way is to ask Mathematica perhaps. These answers are all next to the easiest at best. $:)$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For simple limits like this, the easiest way is often to sandwich the sequence between simpler sequences for which the limit is known.

Notice that $n-1 \leq n$ and $2n+2 \geq 2n$ entail
$$
\frac{n-1}{2n+2} \leq \frac{1}{2}
$$
so that for $n \geq 1$ one has
$$0 \leq \left(\frac{n-1}{2n+2}\right)^n \leq \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0.$$
Conclude with the squeeze theorem.

*Remark.* This method gives more than just the limit:  you get a good estimate of how quickly the sequence converges. For example, it is now easy to give a $n$ such that $\left(\frac{n-1}{2n+2}\right)^n \leq 10^{-100}$.

Answer (score 9):

The limit can be written as $$\frac{\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{-n}\right)^{-1}}{\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}$$

Now use $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1m\right)^m=e$$

Comment: Is this incorrect, another joke, or a legitimate alternative solution?

Comment: @kaine, why? It becomes $$\frac{e^{-1}}{\infty\cdot e}=0$$

Comment: Ok, that is correct.. I didn't follow the solution at first but now it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

$0\le\left(\dfrac{n-1}{2n+2}\right)^n=\dfrac{1}{2^n}\times\dfrac{\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n}\le\dfrac{1}{2^n}\times\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n}\to0$ since $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n\to e$

So by [*squeezing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(n-1 \over 2n+2\right)^n}=0.$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(n - 1 \over 2n + 2\right)^{n}}
=
\lim_{n \to\infty}\bracks{{1 \over 2^{n}}\,
{\pars{1 - 1/n}^{n} \over \pars{1 + 1/n}^{n}}}
=
\lim_{n \to\infty}\pars{{1 \over 2^{n}}\,{\expo{-1} \over e}}
= \color{#0000ff}{\large 0}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{n-1}{2n+2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{n+1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{n+1}$$
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1})^n$$
which is less than your $\frac 1 2$ so it does go to $0$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

$$\left(\frac{n-1}{2n+2}\right)^n=\frac1{2^n}\left(1-\frac2{n+1}\right)^n=$$

$$=\frac1{2^n}\left(1-\frac2{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\left(1-\frac2{n+1}\right)^{-1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

since the second factor's limit above is $\;e^{-2}\;$ , and the third's is $\;1\;$

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate this limit easily by using the root test:
First, we have to make sure that the sequence is bigger or equal to 0 for all n, i think it is quite easy to see it and then:
$$a_n = \left(\frac{n-1}{2n+2}\right)^n$$
$$(a^n)^{1/n}=\frac{n-1}{2n+2} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$$
Therefore, by the root test:
$$a_n \rightarrow 0$$
You can find about the root test here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test, though in this link, it looks more complicated.