# Limit to $e^2$.

Tags: limits

I have to show
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} {\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{1 - x^2}\right)}^{x^2} = e^2,
$$
but I don't get the trick to see it, I suppose I can use something like
$$
{\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} {\left(1 + \frac1x\right)}^x\right)}^2 = e^2,
$$
but I do not see how I can apply to the problem. On the other hand,
$$
\frac{x^2 + 1}{1 - x^2} = 1 + \frac{2 x^2}{1 - x^2}.
$$
Any hint?

Comment: Something isn't quite right here: The limit, as given, does not exist, because $1-x^2$ is negative for $x\gt1$, which means the expression is undefined for most values of $x$. And even if you restrict it, say to *integer* values of $x$, it'll be positive for even integer values and negative for odd integer values, so its limit, if one did exist, could only be $0$. I think you need to have $x^2-1$ in the denominator.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580665/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-left-fracn-1-2n2-rightn/580667#580667 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071229/simple-way-to-compute-lim-x-to-0-left-frac1x12x-right1-x-witho/3071235#3071235

Comment: Probably it is $$\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right)^{x^2}$$

Comment: Furthermore $x^{x^2}\ne (x^x)^2$

Comment: @BarryCipra If you are right then the limit is trivially $1$. The limit I wrote is $e^2$

Comment: why is the limit you wrote $e^2$?

Comment: @Raffaele, oh, you are right. I'll delete that unfortunate comment!

Comment: If I replace $1-x^2$ by $x^2-1$ from the denominator, how can I check that I get $e^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit of interest is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right)^{x^2}$, then we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right)^{x^2}&=\left(\frac{x^2-1+2}{x^2-1}\right)^{x^2}\\\\
&=\left(\left(1+\frac{2}{x^2-1}\right)^{x^2-1}\right)^{x^2/(x^2-1)}
\end{align}$$

Now, use $\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{t}{y}\right)^y=e^t$ with $y=x^2-1$.  Can you wrap this up now?

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: divide both denominator and numerator by $x^2$ and rewrite the quotient as a product where each factor tends to $e$.

Comment: Please note my comment below the OP, which posted about the same time as your answer.